# Using macro variables in datastep arguments

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide, datastep

I'm trying to write tiny programm with parameters to backup datasets *(name+date+time)* in Enterprise Guide. Here's code:

```
data &WhatLib..&WhatTable%str(_)&SYSDATE.%sysfunc(tranwrd(%str(&SYSTIME.),:,_)) ;
set &WhatLib..&WhatTable ;
run;
```

`WhatLib`*(default value work)* and `WhatTable`*(default value _PRODSAVAIL)* - parameters. Well, I get result, that in the screenshot:

[image: first version of code result]

I added a few more strings to check macro variables values:

```
%put &WhatLib..&WhatTable%str(_)&SYSDATE.%sysfunc(tranwrd(%str(&SYSTIME.),:,_));
%put &WhatLib..&WhatTable;
```

And result is in log was:

> work._PRODSAVAIL_22AUG1613_28
>
> work._PRODSAVAIL

Then, I wrapped this code into macro defenition:

```
%macro TEST();
...
<--same code-->
...
%mend TEST;

%TEST();
```

But result were the same.
I will be grateful if you specify an error or feature that I did not realize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%STR(_)` is causing problem here. You don't need to put `_` in the `%STR()` macro function. Underscore is proper part of name in data sets.

Also it is better to use `%SYSFUNC()` with `TIME()` and `DATE()` functions to have actual time and date. Not the SAS starting time and date:

```
data &WhatLib..&WhatTable._%sysfunc(date(),date9.)_%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(time(),hhmm5.),:,_));
   set &WhatLib..&WhatTable;
run;
```